# Does Bestow Curse overrule advantages

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, advantage-and-disadvantage

If a player was to cast bestow curse and apply it onto a creatures wisdom ability score as written they would have disadvantage on ability checks and saving throws made with wisdom. Although if the creature had an advantage on wisdom ability checks and saving throws would they still have disadvantage or would they cancel out as another rule states.

Comment: Do you have much reason to believe they _would not_ cancel out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Disadvantage cancels out advantage and vice versa.

Unless a specific rule you're looking at says otherwise, the standard rule for advantage and disadvantage applies. In this case, there's nothing that says the disadvantage from *bestow curse* negates other advantage in addition.